# How do I send an Email with no "to" address using Mail::Sender?

Tags: perl, email

Is it possible to send an Email with only **cc** or **bcc** recipients using Mail::Sender?  When I try to send an Email without a "to" address, I get the expected return code:

> -8 = argument $to empty

Comment: Beware: A missing To-header is not something that a spam filter takes lightly. For example, SpamAssassin will add at least 1.5 to the spam score of such an email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an empty string `''` in the "to" field does not work.  Using a space works like a charm.

```
use Mail::Sender;

my $sender = Mail::Sender->new();
my $mail   = {
    smtp                 => 'mailserver',
    from                 => 'example@example.com',
    to                   => ' ',
    bcc                  => 'example@example.com',
    subject              => 'test',
    ctype                => 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
    skip_bad_recipients  => 1,
    msg                  => 'test'
};

my $ret =  $sender->MailMsg($mail);

print $ret;
```

Answer (score 2):

Does the `fake_to` parameter work:

> fake_to
>
> => the recipient's address that will be shown in headers. If not specified we use the value of "to".
>
> If the list of addresses you want to send your message to is long or if you do not want the recipients to see each other's address set the fake_to parameter to some informative, yet bogus, address or to the address of your mailing/distribution list.

http://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::Sender

Looking at the source, it seems you'd still need to set the `to` parameter to something.  Perhaps `" "` would do the trick?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using '' ?